# Powershell outlook replace display name with full email address

Tags: powershell, outlook

When i run below PS code, it displays list of required attendees, but it shows the display name. What should i do, so that script display's email address instead.

```
  Function Get-OutlookCalendar {
param ( [DateTime] $rangeStart = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-2)
  , [DateTime] $rangeEnd   = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(+1)) 

$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$session = $outlook.Session
$session.Logon()
$olFolderCalendar = 9
$apptItems = $session.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderCalendar).Items
$apptItems.Sort("[Start]")
$apptItems.IncludeRecurrences = $true
$range = "[End] >= '{0}' AND [Start] <= '{1}'" -f $rangeStart.ToString("g"), $rangeEnd.ToString("g")
$myObject = New-Object System.Object
$result=@()
foreach($appt in $apptItems.Restrict($range)) { 
   $result+=$appt
}
return $result
```

}

Get-OutlookCalendar | %{
$_.RequiredAttendees

}

Current output

```
john, doe; Mark High; Julie, strang
```

Expected Output

```
jdoe@test.com;mhigh@test.com;jstrang@test.com
```

Please let me know and thank you

Comment: The way the required attendees shows is the same as how your outlook displays them. If they are just the names, that’s what will output. Where as if they show as email addresses that is what will be output. Are you using exchange/m365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequiredAttendees` corresponds to the `PR_DISPLAY_TO` MAPI property, which is a a list of display names.

Use the `AppointmentItem.Recipients` collection instead - loop through all recipients and check that `Recipient.Type == olTo` (1), read the `Recipient.Address` property. You might end up with EX type addresses in case of GAL recipients. In that case, use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeuser().PrimarySmtpAddress` property.